# fork() and stderr with terminal

Tags: c, terminal, fork, stderr

I use fork() in order to make different proccesses running and printing a simple message.The result of the code counfuses me though.. Take a look at the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <time.h>


int main(void)
{

    fork();
    fork();
    fork();
    fprintf(stderr,"hello world\n");

}
```

and the output is:

```
mario@ubuntu:~/OS$ ./main
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
mario@ubuntu:~/OS$ hello world
hello world

mario@ubuntu:~/OS$
```

Note that i execute the program at the first line of the terminal but the output is not what i expected. Please help me! Thanks in advance! Same things happen if fprintf is changed with printf("......")

EDIT:I cant understand why the prints are this way. Six before the terminal line one next to it and 1 after it...

Comment: Did you look at how the `fork` function works? Try to guess why you have 8 times 'hello world' using 3 forks. Hint, 8=2^3.

Comment: I know this fact!My problem is not the 8 prints but that they are disrupted by the terminal command. I dont find it reasonable for the program to print 6 before, one next to terminal line (mario@ubuntu:~/OS$ hello world ) and one after..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the parent program exited, the shell running the parent program printed the shell prompt  `mario@ubuntu:~/OS$` on the screen. Any child program which had not printed it's `hello world` by then would be printed after the prompt. If you want the prompt to not appear before all the `hello world`s, you need to make the parent wait for all it's child and grandchild programs to terminate.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279729/how-to-wait-untill-all-child-processes-called-by-fork-complete) to see how to make parent wait.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating 8 processes. Each `fork` divides the process into two. It the original parent finishes the other processes my still be executing. Hence if the original process finishes executing the shell gets a go and prints the prompt despite the other processes are still executing.