# How to make parent wait for all child processes to finish?

Tags: c, process, operating-system, fork, posix

I'm hoping someone could shed some light on how to make the parent wait for *ALL* child processes to finish before continuing after the fork. I have cleanup code which I want to run but the child processes need to have returned before this can happen.

```
for (int id=0; id<n; id++) {
  if (fork()==0) {
    // Child
    exit(0);      
  } else {
    // Parent
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: You'll find the pids returned from all those forks particularly helpful in your task if you care about which child exited and when. Otherwise `wait()` for `n` times.

Answer (score 97):

```
pid_t child_pid, wpid;
int status = 0;

//Father code (before child processes start)

for (int id=0; id<n; id++) {
    if ((child_pid = fork()) == 0) {
        //child code
        exit(0);
    }
}

while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0); // this way, the father waits for all the child processes 

//Father code (After all child processes end)
```

[`wait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) waits for *a* child process to terminate, and returns that child process's `pid`. On error (eg when there are no child processes), `-1` is returned. So, basically, the code keeps waiting for child processes to finish, until the `wait`ing errors out, and then you know they are all finished.

Comment: I wonder if it is safe to assume "error during wait()" equals to "no more childs to wait for".

Comment: `man 2 wait` says: `ECHIILD (for wait()) The calling process does not have any unwaited-for children.` I think you could `#include <errno.h>` and use that in the while.

Answer (score 44):

POSIX defines a function: `wait(NULL)；`. It's the shorthand for `waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);`, which will suspends the execution of the calling process until any one child process exits.
Here, 1st argument of `waitpid` indicates wait for any child process to end.

In your case, have the parent call it from within your `else` branch.

Comment: Thanks for ur replies. I added in wait(NULL) into the non child section, and the program just hangs and the child processes don't even execute ??

Comment: OH, That's not error made by wait(). You should put up your complete code to let me debug it. You code is too simple, just a model.

Comment: The manpage for `wait` says that it waits for **one** of the children to terminate. As @WhozCraig mentioned above you need to `wait` for `n` times.

Comment: Here a more detailed explanation of the **wait** call: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html

Comment: I use `while(wait(NULL) > 0);` so that the process waits for **all** its children to terminate.

Comment: @kotchwane If you do this, then what happens if the process calling `wait()` receives a signal? According to the manpage for `wait()`, `If wait() or waitpid() returns due to the delivery of a signal to the calling process, -1 shall be returned and errno set to [EINTR].`

Answer (score 26):

Use waitpid() like this:

```
pid_t childPid;  // the child process that the execution will soon run inside of. 
childPid = fork();

if(childPid == 0)  // fork succeeded 
{   
   // Do something   
   exit(0); 
}

else if(childPid < 0)  // fork failed 
{    
   // log the error
}

else  // Main (parent) process after fork succeeds 
{    
    int returnStatus;    
    waitpid(childPid, &returnStatus, 0);  // Parent process waits here for child to terminate.

    if (returnStatus == 0)  // Verify child process terminated without error.  
    {
       printf("The child process terminated normally.");    
    }

    if (returnStatus == 1)      
    {
       printf("The child process terminated with an error!.");    
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't wait for all the children to finish just the one child childPid. If there were more processes this wouldn't work.

Comment: Of course if you create more than one thread from a single parent process, you will have to modify this example accordingly.  Providing an example with several forks would have made my answer look confusing.

Comment: how would you modify this code for parent to wait for ALL children to finish?

Comment: @JasonEnochs I don't think is trivial to modify the example for multiple forks. If your code is just "looped" `n` times (put the `waitpid` call in the forking loop), then I think we get a serial execution of the child processes and maybe that's not desired. The answer by @adrisons below looks good.

Answer (score 5):

Just use:

```
while(wait(NULL) > 0);
```

This ensures that you wait for ALL the child processes and only when all have returned, you move to the next instruction.