# Each parent process is not allowed to terminate before its child process

Tags: c, process, fork

I want to create a tree of processes like this P0--->P1--->P2--->P3.

Comment: if(fork()==0) inside an if(fork()==0) etc...

Answer (score 0):

> Each parent process is not allowed to terminate before its child process

Make the parent [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) on its child's end.

See also: [Make parent wait for all child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19461744/694576)