# Executing the program after the "fork part"

Tags: c, semaphore

in my program, I use in main function fork to create 2 processes. Child process do something and parent process is forked again and his child calls another function. Both functions writes to 1 file and all works fine. 
What I need is to write something to the end of file, after both functions and all processes (both functions create processes) finish. 
I tried to write fprintf command everywhere in main and it allways writes somewhere in the middle of file, so I think that the main propably runs parallelly with the 2 functions.
I tried to use semaphore
   `s = sem_open(s1, o_CREATE, 0666, 0);` 
in this way: In the end of each function I wrote `sem_post(s)` and in main I put `sem_wait(s); sem_wait(s);` and after this i wrote fprintf command, but it also didn't work.
Is there some way how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: using `fork` is not *parallel processing* - that is incorrect terminology.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `wait` function. See [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461744/make-parent-wait-for-all-child-processes): `wait(NULL)` will <s>wait for all children to finish</s> wait for a child process to finish (thanks Jonathan Leffler). Call `wait` in a loop to wait for all children processes to finish. Just use that function right before you write to the file in your parent process.

You can also read about the `waitpid` function if you want to wait for a specific process instead of for all the processes.

Edit:
Alternatively, you can actually use semaphores across processes, but it takes a little more work. See [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8359322/how-to-share-semaphores-between-processes-using-shared-memory). The basic idea is to use the function `sem_open` with the `O_CREAT` constant. `sem_open` has 2 function signatures:

`sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag);`

`sem_t *sem_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode, unsigned int value);`

From the [sem_open man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sem_open.3.html):

> ```
>    If O_CREAT is specified in oflag, then two additional arguments must
>    be supplied.  The mode argument specifies the permissions to be
>    placed on the new semaphore, as for open(2).  (Symbolic definitions
>    for the permissions bits can be obtained by including <sys/stat.h>.)
>    The permissions settings are masked against the process umask.  Both
>    read and write permission should be granted to each class of user
>    that will access the semaphore.  The value argument specifies the
>    initial value for the new semaphore.  If O_CREAT is specified, and a
>    semaphore with the given name already exists, then mode and value are
>    ignored.
> ```

In your parent process, call `sem_open` with the mode and value parameters, giving it the permissions you need. In the child process(es), call `sem_open("YOUR_SEMAPHORE_NAME", 0)` to open that semaphore for use.

Comment: Might help to give a brief summary of what each of answers convey rather than dumping links.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that I have it exactly as you wrote it. I have it like:
main:
sem_t *s;
s = sem_open(s1, O_CREAT, 0666, 0);
sem_close(s);
s = sem_open(s1, O_RDWR);

function 1 and two:
sem_t *s;
    s = sem_open(s1, O_RDWR);

"s1" Is a macro.

Comment: Note that [`wait()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/wait.html) waits for one child to die.  You have to use it in a loop to wait for all children to die.  `int corpse; int status; while ((corpse = wait(&status)) != -1) printf("PID %d exited with status 0x%.4X\n", corpse, status);`.  There's still room for angst over signal handling and the like; you can make that more sophisticated if you like.