# Wait for all child processes in fork chain

Tags: c, fork, wait

i want one parent process to create 10 child processes, but how can i make the parent process to wait for all child processes?

i have this given code in C

```
    for(int cnt = 1; cnt<=10; cnt++) {
        switch ( pid = fork() ) {
                case -1:
                    perror("error");
                    break;
                case 0:
                    printf("%d: child process, my PID=%d and PPID=%d\n", cnt, getpid(), getppid() );
                    sleep(10);
                    exit(0);
                break;
                default:
                    printf("%d: parent process, my PID=%d and PPID=%d\n", cnt, getpid(), getppid() );
                    sleep(10);
        }   
    }
}
```

i tried with wait and waitpid in the default part, but it seems that the parent process only waits for the next child process to exit.
how can i make it wait for all 10 child processes to exit?

Comment: See [man 2 waitpid](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) -- with the example at the bottom as well. It will go in the parent block.

Comment: You can count the number of children that you successfully created, and then wait that many times.

Comment: This topic is probably what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461744/how-to-make-parent-wait-for-all-child-processes-to-finish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to loop over the child processes and, if you want, get your status.

Like this:

```
int i, pid, status;
for (i=0; i<10N; i++) {
    pid=wait(&status);
    printf("Arrived child with pid %d - status %d\n", pid, status);
}
```