What happens if fork() fails after some processes are created?
The goal of the code below is to create 4 subprocesses without generating any grandchildren. The code functions correctly if the fork function operates as expected. If fork fails while creating the first subprocess, the code will handle the failure appropriately.
However, I am curious about the case where 3 subprocesses are created, and then the fork fails when creating the fourth subprocess. In this case, if my understanding is correct, the parent process would exit, but the 3 already created subprocesses would still be running.
If so, how can I kil all created subprocesses before the parent process exits?
Edit: I am open to any suggestions to improve the code.
void create_subprocessies(int pids[], int pid_parent)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (pid_parent != getppid())
        {
            if ((pids[i] = fork()) == -1)
            {
                perror("Fork");
                exit(-1);
            }
        }
    }
}


Don't exit right away on error, but wait for the other child processes to terminate (either by themselves, or by sending them some signal to terminate early).

How can i do that?

BTW, it's a weird way to create subprocesses. Usually one would check the return value of fork against 0 to see if it belongs to parent or child.

How can i do that - the same way you are doing it in the end of your program (presumably) ? By using wait()/waitpid().

@EugeneSh. I know it might seem weird, but i want to create 4 subprocesses and store the values returned by fork in the array pids. I'll use this array later in the main function to determine which subprocess should execute what code.

Why do you have pid_parent != getppid() ? Shouldn't it be == ? And you should take this check out of the loop.

No it should be there, I check if the parent of the current process is the same as the original process, in that case do nothing, otherwise create a new process. This way i am certain there would only be 4 subprocessies, i could also use pid_parent == getpid() instead of getppid(). I can't take the check out of the loop because if i do every subprocess would create it's own grandchildren, i would end up with a lot more processies than 4.

This is how you create 4 subprocesses and store them in the array: for (i=0; i < 4; i++) {     pids[i] = fork();     if (pids[i] == 0)         break;     else if (pids[i] == -1) {         // handle error     } }

Thanks, this is a more readable way to create them, could you please review this code, i try to exit properly if the 4th fork for example fails. ```for (int i = 0; i < NB_PROCESSUS; i++)
{
pids[i] = fork();
    if (pids[i] == 0)
        break;

    else if (pids[i] == -1)
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)
        {
            kill(pids[k], SIGTERM);
        }
    }
}```


You are killing them, but you don't wait for them to terminate. You need to wait for each process to terminate before the parent terminates, otherwise you will get zombies. Since you have the children pids you can waitpid for each one explicitly.

Is this what i should do?  else if (pids[i] == -1)         {             for (int k = 0; k < i; k++)             {                 kill(pids[k], SIGTERM);             }             while (wait(NULL) != -1)                 ;         }

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461744/how-to-make-parent-wait-for-all-child-processes-to-finish

Yes, so basically it's what I did right? My subprocessies depend on one another, if one of them is not created nothing will work later in the code so if i fail to create one i want all the others to die. What i did should be correct no?

@EugeneSh. — if the original process exits before its children, then the init process inherits them.  They are not made into zombies.  Zombies are created when the original process does not wait for the children, but when the original process exits, what were zombies are reaped.

How do you distinguish parent from child in caller function? What children processes should do? There is no need to compare pids, just check result of fork(). Your original code seems overcomplicated.

void create_subprocesses(size_t npids, int pids[npids])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < npids; i++)
    {
        if ((pids[i] = fork()) == -1)
        {
            perror("fork() failed");
            for (size_t j = 0; j < i; j++)
                kill(pids[j], SIGTERM);
            exit(-1);
        }
        else if (pids[i] == 0)
        {
            be_childish(…);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
}

Note the revised interface, which fixes a spelling mistake and dictates how many processes should be launched.
The be_childish() function does whatever the child processes are supposed to do.  If it is a _Noreturn function (if it has the attribute [[noreturn]] or equivalent in C23), then the exit() after it is not necessary, but it ensures that the child does not continue, so it's a form of defensive programming.  If the arguments for the children are not easily determined, you likely have design problems.  You may then need to arrange for the children to return, but it isn't likely to be a comfortable design.
You could arrange for the create_subprocesses() function to take a function pointer and an argument:
void create_subprocesses(size_t npids, int pids[npids], void (*child)(void *data), void *data)
{
    …
        else if (pids[i] == 0)
        {
            (*child)(data);  // Or: child(data);
            exit(-1);
        }
   …
}

This assumes that the children all get the same data.   If need be, you can arrange for a different function and different data for each child by passing an array of a structure containing a function pointer and a parameter.
As shown, the function only returns in the parent process after all the children are successfully forked.  The SIGTERM signal indicates to the child that it should terminate.  You could use SIGHUP instead, though it has slightly different connotations.  You should not normally use SIGKILL or other signals.
